Is it possible to calculate the moon age from the phase angle?
Given the phase angle of the moon (i) on degrees (0-360), is it possible to calculate its "age" in days?

You could roughly approximate it by $ age=PA/360*29.5 $.  But the time taken to move a certain number of degrees isn't constant, so you need more information and a better algorithm for more accuracy.

@GregMiller I did try that however that approximation is not satisfactory. Is there another way to calculate it? My calculations are based on the book Astronomical Algorithms by Jean Meeus. I have everything calculated up to the illuminated fraction of the moon (k).

Here's a link to another approximation.  But if you can compute the phase, why not just compute the last new moon and count the days? https://www.celestialprogramming.com/snippets/moonage.html

@GregMiller: Nice snippet, but isn’t the precision a little “false advertising”? You should limit it to one or two decimals…

@GregMiller Because the process on the book is a little bit too much with 14 extra arguments + 25 corrections + another additional 14 corrections. Thank you, I'll try that method when I get on the PC later.

@PierrePaquette The decimals are required so the average is valid over a long range of time even though the individual predictions won't be accurate to that many decimals.

@GregMiller it works fine and way closer to the correct result. Thank you. I'd mark it as an answer but I have no idea how. I'll probably do the correct calculations later on though.
